# How to enter SWTOR's Flashpoint "The Esseles" in Veteran mode?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

My friend and I are starting a playthrough of SWTOR. We've done the Flashpoint "*The Esseles*" on Story Mode a few times now, and wanted to try it on Veteran Mode. However, whatever we try, we always end up in a Story Mode version.

The steps we take:

1. Group up freshly
2. Start conversation to pick up the quest
3. Both choose "*Veteran Mode*" when the options in the chat wheel pop up
4. Both make sure the "*Mission Difficulty Preference*" is set to "*Veteran*"
5. Make sure the instance phase has been reset, to prevent old instances from troubling us
6. Run into the instance

However:

- The result: we get thrown into a Story Mode flashpoint, and a related Story Mode quest pops up
- Expected: starting the Veteran Mode flashpoint

Here's a screenshot of most of the above points visible:

[image: quest log overview]

Is there some trick or setting we need to use to enter "The Esseles" on Veteran Mode?

Comment: I believe Veteran mode is split into level 10-15 and 16+ sections.  Are you both in the same level range?  You might also need to use Group Finder for the first range, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missions you currently have in your log are both for Veteran Esseles. Or rather, the mission "[FLASHPOINT] The Esseles" is difficulty-agnostic - it is the same on all difficulty levels. When entering a flashpoint on Story mode, you should have a "[STORY] Flashpoint:..." mission and (in most cases) will receive server messages about the GSI Combat Support Droid. (I've actually not done Story mode flashpoints in a group before, so I don't know if the droid is only for true solo runs.)

Note that the "two players recommended" in the Veteran Esseles description is not an error; unlike every other flashpoint, The Esseles (and its Imperial counterpart, The Black Talon) was originally designed for two players.

Comment: Gosh, you were right! How confusing :) - Thx a bunch!